# Add context menu entry to TextEditor

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I want to add a custom menu item to the context menu of the default text editor in eclipse.

I can add a menu entry to all context menus with

```
<menuContribution locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any?after=additions">
    <command commandId="HelloPlugin2.commands.sampleCommand" label="My Test" style="push" />
</menuContribution>
```

but I want it to be shown only in the current editors context menu, so i tried

```
 <menuContribution locationURI="popup:#TextEditorContext?after=additions">
    <command commandId="HelloPlugin2.commands.sampleCommand" label="My Test" style="push" />
</menuContribution>
```

but unfortunately the item is not visible...

Can anybode help me out?
Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure it is the default text editor? Other editors based on the text editor have a different context menu id.

Comment: You are right! I opened a plain .txt file and the context menu for this editor shows my item. So my question is now: How can I find out the id of my editor? I want my item to be shown whenever a .java file is being edited...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base text editor context menu id is `#TextEditorContext` but other editors based on the  text editor normally override this using the `setEditorContextMenuId` method.

Looking at the `setEditorContextMenuId` calls the Java text editor context menu id appears to be `#CompilationUnitEditorContext` (and `#ClassFileEditorContext` if a .class file is being edited).

Answer (score 0):

I found that #TextEditorContext does not show up on *.java file editor which has extension of #CompilationUnitEditorContext.

Using Plugin Spy I found, that every text editor uses #AbstractTextEditorContext. This can work for any kind of text editor.